# Manipulating array data to actually save, write, and change the data content

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs, overwrite

I am new to AngularJS and so far I'm loving it but I am having a hard time manipulating my data with it. I have an array of data with the attributes name:'', description:'', type:'', ... etc ... and I have enough data but not enough yet for me to upload it onto a server. My problem is that I want to be able to change and update my data using a form or input.

Here is my scripts/admin.js where I implement function submitTheForm() that I call with the submit button.

```
 angular.module('myApp')

//filter to get a specific $scope.campaigns using its id
.filter('getById', function() {
  return function(input, id) {
    var i=0, len=input.length;
    // alert(input.length);
    for (; i<len; i++) {
      if (+input[i].id === +id) {
        return input[i];
      }
    }
    return input[0];
  };
})

.controller('AdminCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter) {
    //<--ARRAY OF DATA with multiple attributes<--
    $scope.campaigns = [
    { name:'', description'', etc... etc...},
    {...Lots of Data...},
    {...Lots of Data...},
    {...Lots of Data...},
    {...Lots of Data...},
    ];

    $scope.selectCampaign = function(object) {
        $scope.selectedCampaign = object;
    };

    $scope.submitTheForm = function(item, event) {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to edit?") == true) {
            alert("--> Submitting form");
            var dataObject = {
                name : $scope.selectedCampaign.name, description: $scope.selectedCampaign.description, type: $scope.selectedCampaign.type, imgSrc:  $scope.selectedCampaign.imgSrc, brand:  $scope.selectedCampaign.brand, region:  $scope.selectedCampaign.region, location:  $scope.selectedCampaign.location, contact:  $scope.selectedCampaign.contact, url:  $scope.selectedCampaign.url, id: $scope.selectedCampaign.id
             };
             console.log(dataObject);
             var campaign = $scope.selectedCampaign;
             var id = campaign.id;
             var found = $filter('getById')($scope.campaigns, id);


             // setTimeout(function(){ $scope.$apply($scope.selectedCampaign = dataObject); });
         }
    };
}]);
```

Here is my main.html where I have my input and submit button

```
  <div class="row modalDetail">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 detailLeft text-left">
      <div class="middle-allign">
        <h1 class="detailName">
          <input type="text" ng-model="selectedCampaign.name" name="name">
        </h1>
        <div class="detailDescription">
          <textarea rows="5" cols="71" name="description" ng-model="selectedCampaign.description"></textarea>
        </div>
        <table class="detailTable table">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="bolder">Brand</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" ng-model="selectedCampaign.brand" name="brand" >
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="bolder">Campaign Type</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" ng-model="selectedCampaign.type" name="type">
              </td>
            </tr><tr>
              <td class="bolder">Region</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" ng-model="selectedCampaign.region" name="region">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="bolder">Contact</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" ng-model="selectedCampaign.contact" name="contact">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="bolder">Location</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" ng-model="selectedCampaign.location" name="location">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="bolder">URL</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" ng-model="selectedCampaign.url" name="url">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

        <div class="detailCta">
          <button class="btn detailButton" ng-click="submitTheForm()">Submit Campaign</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

I am trying to utilize 'ng-model' to bind the data and it all works fine but it does not actually change the array content within my main.html. When I refresh it all just goes back to how my array content is. This is because I haven't actually over-written my array content. How can I go about making a absolute change/over-write to the actual object within the array content?

I feel as though it is as simple as $scope.campaigns.push(campaign); except instead of 'push' it would be 'update' or 'over-write'

Comment: When you refresh the page it goes back? Well, that is not very surprising when you don't save the updated values anywhere.

Comment: @dirkk Exactly, could you direct me to the tools that do that? I am still currently researching.

Comment: https://www.firebase.com/quickstart/angularjs.html has a free plan, and is great for saving data without having your own backend.

Comment: @dave I will definitely check it out but I would still like to figure out if it is possible to directly change my array contents using JS and Angular.

Comment: You want to overwrite the javascript file from the client?  No, not likely possible.  You could probably use localStorage to at least persist it to the clients browser.

Comment: I have it currently 'push'ing to the array but it does not survive the page refresh. I think it'd be best to upload to a db. I'm currently deploying via heroku and it will be my first time uploading data to the heroku database. Do you have any tips uploading my current angularjs data to the heroku postgres database?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the values in the server, you should see [ngResource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) to create entry points to get and save (and delete) data. Alternatively, you can use the lower level service [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

If you want to store the data in your current script (it will last until the page is **refreshed** in the browser - F5), you should do some changes:

```
.controller('AdminCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', '$rootScope', function($scope, $filter, $rootScope) {
    //<--ARRAY OF DATA with multiple attributes<--

    if ($rootScope.campaigns === undefined) {
        $rootScope.campaigns = [
            { name:'', description'', etc... etc...},
            {...Lots of Data...},
            {...Lots of Data...},
            {...Lots of Data...},
            {...Lots of Data...},
        ];
    }
    $scope.campaigns = $rootScope.campaigns;
    //don't even think this above line is needed, since $scope inherits from $rootScope, but I've put it for clarity.

    $scope.selectCampaign = function(object) {
        $scope.selectedCampaign = object;
    };

    $scope.submitTheForm = function(item, event) {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to edit?") == true) {
            alert("--> Submitting form");
            var dataObject = {
                name : $scope.selectedCampaign.name, description:     $scope.selectedCampaign.description, type: $scope.selectedCampaign.type, imgSrc:      $scope.selectedCampaign.imgSrc, brand:  $scope.selectedCampaign.brand, region:      $scope.selectedCampaign.region, location:  $scope.selectedCampaign.location, contact:      $scope.selectedCampaign.contact, url:  $scope.selectedCampaign.url, id:     $scope.selectedCampaign.id
             };
             console.log(dataObject);
             var campaign = $scope.selectedCampaign;
             var id = campaign.id;
             var found = $filter('getById')($scope.campaigns, id);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Notice how I bind it to $rootScope.campaigns - so if you navigate to another ng-view and then come back, the data is still here.

However, if you want your data survive the F5, you must either use the server side options I gave you. or use Local Storage.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yea I have it currently 'push'ing to the array but like you said it does not survive the page refresh. I'm currently deploying via heroku and it will be my first time uploading data to heroku database. Do you have any tips uploading my current angularjs data to the heroku postgres database?

Comment: Yes: you need a backend technology. I don't know what are you using (PHP, NodeJS, Python, Java, ...). I don't know what preconfigured packages or app do you have, but accessing a database involves a password, and in such way... you need server-side (this means: having a database password in client-side is an open door for malicius lammers to your site). So: once you decide what server-side technology to use, you'll discover on your own what technology fits your needs.